# Showing a scrollbar only in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, webkit

I'd like to have a scrollbar at the bottom of the div but this CSS works only in Firefox, not Webkit browsers like Safari or Chrome.

```css
div.hoge {
    width: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I googled and found some pages mentioning you should use `overflow-x` or `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` but they didn't work either. Need to use some JSs? Any guesses?

Comment: Are you using Lion? Webkit browsers hide their scroll bars when not in use on osx 10.7.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burhans/vcA5b/) of a div that scrolls on x.  If you don't include the `white-space: nowrap`, then the text just wraps within the div and only the vertical (y-direction) scroll bar actually scrolls.

The fiddle shows two div elements; one with `nowrap` and one without.  Also I put borders on the div to make it easier to see.

Answer (score 1):

- If you need a scroll bar to appear always then, you can use `overflow: scroll`
- If you need vertical scroller then, `overflow-y: scroll`
- If you need only horizontal scroller then, `overflow-x: scroll`

***As per the questions title:*** You can write mozilla specific styles like this

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {

    div.hoge {
        width: 500px;
        overflow: auto;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `overflow-x:scroll;` ?

Also make sure that the div.hoge has the enough height to display the scroll bar at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

overflow: auto; doesn't make scrolling DIV, use overflow: scroll;
if you want it on any particular axis, then use overflow-x: scroll; or overflow-y: scroll;